# Problemas al refrescar una pagina usando Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla con una serie de registros, marco con checkbox varios de ellos. Hago clic en un botón que actualiza los registros, lo que hace es llamar un script php a través de Ajax tantas veces como registros seleccionados tengo.

Bien una vez finalizado se recarga la página con un window.location.reload(); y sorpresa de los registros que he marcado, por ej: 6 sólo me ha actualizado 4(estos valores son orientativos porque van cambiando, incluso en ocasiones los actualiza todos) La única manera que tengo de ver la información correctamente actualizada es recargar la página web desde el navegador.

Os pongo el código que utilizo para la petición Ajax y la posterior recarga de la página:

```
$('#canviestat').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {             // Selection of id f the checkboxes of the checked rows

              var arrayCod = new Array();
              var arraySaldo = new Array();

              $('#tableprod').find('tbody tr').each(function () {             // Loop every rows of the table

                  var $button = $(event.relatedTarget);                       // Button that triggered the modal
                  var row = $(this);
                  var cod = (this.id);
                  var saldo;

                  if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {    // Add the id_fichaje to array
                        console.log(cod);
                        arrayCod.push(cod);
                        arraySaldo.push(row.find("td[data-field='saldo']").text());   // Envío cálculo de saldo
                  }
              });

              if (arrayCod.length != 0){                                     // If array contents id then...
                  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                  $('#codigosSeleccionados').text(arrayCod.length + " codis seleccionats");

                  $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event){

                      event.preventDefault();

                      var inputvalue = $(this).attr("value");               // Get the  value of the input fields

                      $.each( arrayCod, function( key, value ) {                // Loop arrayCod and call ajax to update estado    

                                 $.ajax({
                                         url:"updateEstado.php",
                                         type:"POST",
                                         data:{"estado": inputvalue, "id_fichaje": value, "saldo": arraySaldo[key]},
                                             dataType:"text",
                                             success:function(data){
                                      $('#canviestat').modal('hide');                       //Close window modal
                        $('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll');   
                                          }
                                      });
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] != ''){

                include("db_tools.php");
                include("functions.php");

                $conn = dbConnect("localhost", "5432", "-", "-", "-");

                $estado = $_POST['estado'];
                $estado = Estado($estado);

                $id_fichaje = $_POST['id_fichaje'];
                $saldo = $_POST['saldo'];

                $username = $_SESSION['username'];

                $query = "UPDATE produccion.estado SET usuario='{$username}', estado='{$estado}', fecha_mod=now() WHERE id_fichaje = '{$id_fichaje}'";

                $result = pg_query($conn, $query);

                pg_close($conn);

        } else{
            ?>
            <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="text-center">
                  <p class='errorLogin'>La sessió no està activa, si us plau login <a href="login.php">aquí</a></p>
              </div>
        </div>
<?php
        }?>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Codigo jquery actualizado.

He detectado que da un error la consola de depuración al enviar multiples registros para la actualización:

*/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js:4 XHR failed loading: POST "https://addtime.addvantage.es/updateEstado.php".*

En el código jquery lo que hago es recorrer todos los checkbox seleccionados y enviar al post uno a uno, es decir, en un bucle.

Comment: El código de Ajax no nos dice nada sobre cómo se están actualizando los datos, habría que ver en primera instancia las variables que le envías al servidor y tu script de php para ver cómo están siendo procesados por favor

Comment: @Lixus actualizado con el código php

Comment: En la función success de ajax no realizas ninguna acción con el resultado que te devuelve (data), por lo que no veo como estas actualizando los datos. Envías en la llamada ajax el campo "saldo", este campo entiendo es el que contiene tus checks pero en el código PHP no haces uso de este.

Comment: Mi pregunta es **¿por qué recargas la página?**, ¡si Ajax existe precisamente para que no la recargues!, puedes hacer cualquier cambio en ella sin tener que moverte de ahí, Ajax gestiona en background todas las idas y venidas al servidor, mandando y trayendo los datos que hagan falta.

Answer (score 1):

Si al final vas ha hacer un `window.reload` no tiene sentido que hagas cambios en el `onsuccess`, por ejemplo quitar todos los `checks`.

Por otro lado, al recargar una misma URL estás cargando en la mayoría de los casos la versión que el navegador tiene en caché, por eso ves parte de los checks marcados y si recargas los ves todos.

**Un modo de resolverlo:**

- elimina el uncheck del onsuccess: los que están seleccionados permanecen seleccionados, se van a corresponder con lo que registras en la página siguiente
- elimina el reload: la finalidad de usar esta estructura ajax es evitar recargar la página completa, y sólo actualizar aquellas partes de la página que lo requieran

Esta opción en tu código mantiene los checks que has hecho de forma natural al seleccionar, no borras los seleccionados y no cambias los no seleccionados, no recargas.

```
 $.ajax({
       url:"updateEstado.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{"estado": inputvalue, 
             "id_fichaje": value, 
             "saldo": arraySaldo[key]},
       dataType:"text",
       success:function(data){
              $('#canviestat').modal('hide'); //Close window modal
              //$('#tableprod').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll'); // Unchecked all checkboxes
              //window.location.reload(); // Recargar página
              }
   });
```

**Otra opción si quieres que se recargue la página:**

- envía el formulario html a tu archivo destino
- en el archivo destino envía a la página inicial con `window.location` y para evitar la caché puedes añadir cualquier variable a la URL, por ejemplo: "miformulario.php?valid=1".

En esta segunda opción tu tabla estaría contenida en un form, y haces el proceso "natural" de envío del form y todos sus campos (los checks que hayas realizado y el resto de variables que necesites) con un botón tipo submit. En el archivo php de destino recoges y tratas los datos (actualización de base de datos) y al acabar lo reenvías a la página de form, es decir la vuelves a cargar.

Página 1 con el formulario: `miformulario.php`

Página 2 destino del formulario: `updateEstado.php`. En la página 2 después de meter los datos en la base de datos, es decir al final del if, reenvías a la página del formulario. Para evitar la caché añades una variable que hace diferente la url (hay otros modos de evitar la caché del navegador pero este es el más sencillo para el caso), y que además puedes usar para confirmarle al usuario que los datos se han procesado correctamente.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location="miformulario.php?procesado=1";
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Carmen. El problema no es que se me quedan los unchecks marcados algunos y otros no. El problema es que no me actualiza el contenido de la página correctamente, es decir, si actualizo 8 registros, normalmente hay 2 o 3 que no veo los cambios actualizados hasta que recargo la página manualmente.

Comment: me gustaría que recargara los elementos los cuales he actualizado mediante el código php. Podrías orientarme de como hacerlo?

Comment: @Rumar he editado la respuesta para que puedas aplicar las opciones que comentaba.

Comment: Gracias @Carmen por el interés. He probado lo que me dices pero no me ha funcionado. Voy a poner mas detalles en el post para ver si podemos encontrar la solución.

Comment: he añadido el código que me has indicado en updateEstado.php pero en ningún momento me devuelve esa URL en el navegador. Después he probado de ponerla al final del codigo jquery pero no tiene sentido no me daba ningún resultado.